# java selenium test on Ubuntu VDS. The site does not load completely

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

When you run a java application with a test on an Ubuntu server, chrome starts successfully, but when you go to the site, it does not find the necessary elements. Judging by the screenshots, the site is not fully loaded. Delay naturally doesn't help.
What could be the problem?